# Is There any way or third party support to convert CSV file to PDF in cocoa app swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Hi I am working on Cocoa app where I have CSV file. I want to convert that CSV file to PDF format.

Comment: No, there's none. What is the PDF supposed to look like? A table? A simple line by line appearance? And why CSV? This is an outmoded format without a clear specification.

Comment: Hi PDF will be tableview data with header I am able to convert tableView data to PDF but its not showing table column as header in PDF. I am also exporting Table view data as CSV in which everything is fine so I thought may be there is any way or third party through that I can convert CSV to PDF in Mac app.

Comment: From your comment it looks like you are asking the wrong question. What you draw on screen using Cocoa can also be drawn into a PDF, and it appears you have a TableView for which you have done exactly that so you know already this. Your issue appears to be that your PDF is not what you expected - something is missing. Why not ask a question about that? Show the code you have, what you expected for output, what you got, where you're stuck finding the problem, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you. Trying to produce the PDF via CSV is unlikely to be your answer. HTH